# In Gene Wolfe’s “Black Shoes” what did the narrator do for the mermen?

Tags: black-shoes

In the Gene Wolfe short story “Black Shoes” (Collected in "Starwater Strains", originally appeared in a collection named "13 Horrors", ISBN 978-0935128048) the narrator (who is actually telling his story to the person who is writing it down) says:

> I did them a certain favour and promised to do certain things.

Is it possible to guess what the favour and the promise were?